# Difference between calculated value in PHP and the same value inserted in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm having a really strange problem. I'm developing a custom WordPress plugin and I have a database table which has a column named `pending_balance` which is a `decimal(8,8)` datatype. And on the other hand I have this code (which is actually a cron job):

```
    if ( ! empty( $subscriptions ) ) {
      foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
        if($subscription->status != "inactive") {

          // Calculating $new_pending_balance

          error_log($algorithm . " - " . $new_pending_balance . PHP_EOL, 3, WCM_PLUGIN_DIR . 'error.log');

          $wpdb->update(
              $table_name,
              array( 'pending_balance' => $new_pending_balance ),
              array( 'id' => $subscription->id ),
              array( '%f' ),
              array( '%d' )
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

When the cron job runs I can clearly see the new logs in `error.log`. For example:

```
bitcoin - 0.00038531
litecoin - 0.10420367
ethereumclassic - 1.27727247
```

And when I open the database table so I can see the new pending balance for `ethereumclassic` it says `0.99999999` and not `1.27727247`. I've tried many things like converting the `$new_pending_balance` to 100% exact same datatype, I've tried to do a RAW query instead of using the `->update()` method on the `$wpdb`. The only thing I haven't tried yet is to change the column datatype to string so I can have no problems. But I'm afraid doing this as everywhere inside the plugin the calculations are with the pure value retrieved from the database and I'm actually retrieving a float number from the database right now. If I change it to a string it may cause bugs. What can I do, guys?

Comment: how does the update/insert code look like?

Comment: Wdym, I literally provided it. the `$wpdb->update()`.

Comment: decimal(8,8) cannot hold 1.anything quite obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DECIMAL(8,8)` means eight digits can be stored, eight of which are decimals. That leaves no room for your `1` in `1.27727247`; your column can store values from `-0.99999999` to `0.99999999`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

> Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the salary column range from -999.99 to 999.99.

You should consider turning on [MySQL's "strict mode"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict), which would've given you an "out of range" error instead of silently converting the value.

Comment: What should I consider doing then? I must store values like `1.91837685`, `9.18569584`, `17.01938475`, `93.01928374`

Comment: use 16,8 for example  or 9,8 if only one additional digit is expected

Comment: @howtogeek24 Work with the smallest denominator - satoshis (Bitcoin) or their equivalent in each currency - to avoid floating point issues. Or increase the first number.